Postdoc in Math/Quantum Information with Multiple Interests
I’m about two years away from completing my PhD in Applied Mathematics (fingers crossed). I’m interested in pursuing a postdoc, and I would like to start learning about the process. My research focuses on mathematical problems arising in quantum information science. Specifically, I am interested in the following topics:

Analysis of Quantum Algorithms
Mathematics of Topological Quantum Computation

Most of my current work is in area 1, but I aim to complete a project in area 2 before I graduate. I am actively building my background in area 2 through reading papers, self-study and talking with faculty and post-docs, and I intend to pursue research in both areas during my postdoc and beyond.
How can I structure my postdoc application to highlight both my primary research focus and a secondary interest, even if I have limited project experience in the latter? Is it feasible to secure a postdoc position that aligns with my secondary area of interest, and how realistic is it to expand my research agenda during a postdoc?
In short, I’m seeking insight into how PIs hire postdocs and what the best strategy is for securing a position, especially if one doesn’t have extensive experience in a secondary research area.
