Finding Postdoc Positions in Math/Quantum Information
I’m about two years away from completing my PhD in Applied Mathematics (fingers crossed). I’m interested in pursuing a postdoc, and I would like to start learning about the process. My research focuses on mathematical problems arising in quantum information science. Specifically, I am interested in the Analysis of Quantum Algorithms and Mathematics of Topological Quantum Computation
How can I find postdoc positions in mathematics and where are they typically listed? Are postdoc positions typically advertised by individual PIs or departments? Do I apply directly to a specific PI’s group/project, or is the process more like graduate school applications, where I apply to the department as a whole? How does this process differ in fields like computer science?

Could you clarify how this question differs from your other one https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/213688/postdoc-in-math-quantum-information-with-multiple-interests

I was told my initial post had too many questions. So I made two posts instead. This post is about getting to know more about the logistics of applying for postdoc positions. The other question is more about understanding the application process and how to present a strong profile given my different interests under the umbrella of math and quantum.

A vast majority of mathematics positions at US institutions are currently advertised at mathjobs.org.

Are postdoc positions typically advertised by individual PIs or departments? Do I apply directly to a specific PI’s group/project, or is the process more like graduate school applications, where I apply to the department as a whole?

@user82261 It varies. You'll get a better perspective than I can synthesize by going to mathjobs, filtering by postdocs, sorting by post date, and then checking adverts.
